# Нужно найти слова с четным количеством букв и сменить местами от центра слова левую и правую часть слова

Tags: c++-cli

если введем слово  " ПРИВЕТ " то на выходе должно быть "ВЕТПРИ" если слово нечетное то оставить как было.
Я попытался что то сделать но неполучается(((

```
private: System::Void button1_Click(System::Object^  sender, System::EventArgs^  e) {
               char A[200];
             String^ s1= gcnew String(textBox1->Text);
             String^ s2 = gcnew String("");
             int k=0,b=0;
             int Ind1[100],ind=0;
             for ( int i=0;i<s1->Length-1;i++)
             {
                 if (s1[i]==' '&& s1[i+1]!=' ')
                     {k++;
                 Ind1[ind]=i;
                 ind++;}

             }
              for ( int i=0;i<ind;i++)
             {
                label1->Text=label1->Text+"["+Ind1[i].ToString()+"] ";
             }
              label2->Text=label2->Text+k.ToString();


                  for (int j=ind;j>0;j--)
                  {
                      if ((Ind1[j]-Ind1[j-1])%2==0)
                      {
                            b++;
                      }

                  }

                  for(int i=0;i<s1->Length;i++){
                  A[i]=s1[i];
                  }
                  int x,y,z;
              for(int i=0;i<ind;i++)
              {
                  if (Ind1[i]%2==0)
                  {
                      x=Ind1[i]/2;
                      for(int j=0;j<s1->Length;j++)
                      {
                          if (j!=Ind1[i])
                          {
                              std::swap(A[j],A[j+x]);

                          }
                      }
                  }
              }

              label3->Text=label3->Text+b.ToString();

             /*for (int i=0;i<ind;i++)
             {
                 for (int j=0;j<Ind1[i];j++)
                 {
                     if ()
                 }
             }*/
         }
};
```

}

Comment: я на Visual c++ делал

Comment: Немогу на втором текст боксе вывести изза того что . оказывается нельзя изменять значение если String^ s1   можно только приравнивать.

Comment: Я сам разобрался

Comment: только оно работает только для одного слова а для того чтобы работало чтоб из строки брал нудно понасоздать char S2 3 4 5 6 и тд

Answer (score 1):

После токо как выспался меня вдруг озарило и решил сам свою задачу)))

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include <iostream>
#include <clocale>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdio.h>
using namespace System;

const char separator[]=" ";
const int N=255;

void init(char S[N])
{
for(int i=0;i<N;i++)
{
    S[i]='\0';
}
}

int main(array<System::String ^> ^args)
{
setlocale(LC_ALL,"");
char S[]="привет";

char S1[N];
init(S1);
char *temp = new char[strlen(S)];
strcpy(temp,S);
int count_my_words=1;
char *Ptr = NULL;
Ptr=strtok(S,separator);
while(Ptr)
{
    switch (count_my_words)
    {
    case 1 : strcpy(S1,Ptr); count_my_words++; break;
}
    Ptr=strtok(0,separator);
}
std::cout<<S1<<"\n";
std::cout<<" After : ";
std::cout<<std::endl;
if((strlen(S1))%2==0)
{
char n[100];
int k=0;
int p;
p=strlen(S1)/2;
    for(int i=0;i<strlen(S1);i++)
{
    n[k]=S1[i];
    k++;
}
    for(int i=0;i<k;i++)
    {
        std::swap(n[i],n[i+p]);
        if(i>=p-1)
            break;
    }
    for(int i=0;i<k;i++)
    {
        std::cout<<n[i];
    }
    std::cout<<std::endl;
}
strcpy(S,temp);
system("pause");
return 0;
}
```